# How to have my app to collect GPS when our app is not running on iOS?

Tags: ios, gps

all,

We have an app that mostly is just being used by our internal employees and we have our own enterprise license instead of going through apple store.  We want the app be able to log driving GPS all the time, from 9:00am to 5:00pm, even when our app is not running, of course with user's permission.

So, when our app is running either in front or in background, it has no problem to collect GPS data. However, sometimes when the ipad goes to sleep and our app gets killed, is there anyway to ask the system to wake our app up and update the gps update if there is a significant gps change? Or defer those updates to our app when our app starts? And if it is possible, does it require us to go through app store instead of using enterprise license(which is what we heard before)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exact your requirements, but battery drain could be a huge problem in that kind of application.

To answer your question is possible to make your app run on background and still logging location data. The only thing you should do is activate the background location updates.[image]
The trick do work also for enterprise program. If precise data is not what you need you can simply activate the `- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` with that method activated the device will log less data with less precision, but the benefits in battery duration are huge.
There is a really well written use cases written by Apple have a [look](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).
[UPDATE]
Here is what Apple says about significant location changes

> If you leave the significant-change location service running and your
>   iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service
>   automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At
>   wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a
>   small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location
>   services and process the location data. (You must manually restart
>   location services in the background before any pending location
>   updates can be delivered, as described in “Knowing When to Start
>   Location Services.”) Because your app is in the background, it must do
>   minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that
>   might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If
>   it does not, your app will be terminated. If an iOS app needs more
>   time to process the location data, it can request more background
>   execution time using the
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method of the
>   UIApplication class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andrea.  What if the ipad goes to sleep and our app is killed, or user exits our app and hits the power button to turn off the screen. Will the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges still work? Does it activate our background thread?   Thanks.

Comment: This method works in every case except in iOS7.0 if the app is killed by the user, the main differences between activating a background mode is that you have a very short amount of time before the app is suspended again. I update the answer.